# Cannot change brightness on Samsung rv411 laptop computer

Tags: brightness

I am using a Samsung RV411 s03 laptop computer. I have tried several linux distribution on my laptop computer; I have got a problem with them which is the brightness of the monitor cannot be changed by any methods including using the Fn key and up or down arrow keys and changing the grub property. I finally think the problem is caused by the driver program which is not installed because I have tried that when I was installing the windows 7 but it has be solved when I installed the driver program. However there is no corresponding driver program for linux. Therefore I would like to ask for your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try a workaround that might help.

Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and issue the following command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Search for the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`

proofread, save the document and update grub with the following command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your PC and check now if you can change the brightness with Fn keys.

Answer (score 0):

Or install the EASY DISPLAY MANAGER, that one will enable all FN functions on the keyboard. I have a Samsung RV411, erased completeply and in the setup i discovered this that i am telling you :-D